# Laravel unable to delete records, but methods are specified as delete

Tags: php, laravel

I want to delete records from database through my website. I have specified my methods as DELETE but it doesn't seem to be working.

In my form method, I have specified it as DELETE

```
<form method = "DELETE" action = "/admin_delete_bitstamp/{{ $data->bitstamp_api_id }}">
    <button type = "submit" name = "delete" class = "btn">Delete</button>
</form>
```

In my routes file, I have also specified it as DELETE

```
Route::delete("/admin_delete_bitstamp/{id}", "Bitstamp_Access_C@destroy");
```

This is my delete function

```
public function destroy($id) {
    $api = Bitstamp_Access_M::find($id);
    $api->delete();
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

The error message that I am getting is "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE."

I apologize if this is a rookie mistake.

Comment: please show your delete query

Comment: HTML forms don't support `DELETE`. Hints about this issue can be found in the documentation (search for: form delete).

Comment: did you try with `<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">` inside your form?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ I tried your method, and I got a 419 Page Expired error.

Comment: you must include the CSRF token too. You can doit with @csrf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try following code in view file:

```
<form method = "POST" action = "/admin_delete_bitstamp/{{ $data->bitstamp_api_id }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <button type = "submit" name = "delete" class = "btn">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I got my update method working as well.